# MySQL Query - Need to list rank including duplicates for specific classificaiton

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I need to get the students with the top 5 GPA's. There are some records that have the same GPA value, and in this case, they need to count for the same rank.

If there are 10 students, 3 have the same GPA, I need to return 7 records in order by highest GPA.

Finally, I need to bring back records for only freshmen.
Here is what I have tried:

```
Select s.StudentID, s.GPA, s.Classification
From Student s
Join (Select distinct GPA from Student Order By GPA desc limit 5) b on a.GPA = b.GPA")
```

This brings back the top 5 records for all students. I am needing help finding where do I add `Where Classification = 'Freshman'`.

Is a where clause all I need, or is there a better way to do this?

This is being done in MySQL so I cannot use DenseRank or anything easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select s.StudentID, s.GPA, s.Classification
From Student s
Join (Select distinct GPA from Student 
      where Classification = 'Freshman' 
      Order By GPA desc limit 5) b 
on s.GPA = b.GPA
where s.Classification = 'Freshman' 
order by s.GPA desc
```

Comment: You will also need the filter in the subquery

Comment: Could you explain where that would go? For some reason the query @vkp gave is only bringing back 3 records and I know there are more.

Comment: True. Otherwise you'll get non-freshman gpas, and you could end up with gpas for which there are no freshmen.